# Count quantity of results for duplicate rows sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this:

```
 customer         employee
------        ---------
  A              Adam
  A              Adam
  A              Adam
  B              Bob
  C              Adam
  C              Adam
  B              Bob
  D              Dan
```

I'm trying to figure out how to show how many times Adam has had repeat customers and how many times Bob has.
So in the example above it would return:

Adam => 2 (he's had 2 repeat customers, customer A and C)

Bob => 1 (he's had 1 repeat customer, customer b)

Dan => 0 (he's only had one customer, no repeats)

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY employee
HAVING cnt > 1
```

But I just can't seem to get the rest of the way.

Comment: Your SQL also provide right result . you may test this SQL==>SELECT id,customer,employee,COUNT(*) FROM USER  GROUP BY employee HAVING COUNT(*)>0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to find the repeat customer:

```
SELECT employee,customer FROM yourtable GROUP BY employee, customer having COUNT(*) > 1;
```

After that you can find how many repeat customers each employee has had:

```
SELECT employee, COUNT(*) from (
 SELECT employee,customer 
  FROM yourtable 
  GROUP BY employee, customer 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ) t
GROUP BY employee;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below query :

```
SELECT 
    t.employee, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    (SELECT 
        employee, customer, COUNT(*) AS actcnt
    FROM
        customers
    GROUP BY customer , employee HAVING actcnt > 1) AS t
GROUP BY t.employee
ORDER BY t.employee;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87bd8/1/0)

Comment: That does seem to be doing the trick. But I'm not quite understanding a few things. Is there a reason for the t before employee (t.employee)? Also where would the table identifier go in this?

Comment: @Robbie t is the output of INNER QUERY

Comment: Table identifier will be closed after returning result to outer query which is now 't' will work as identifier

Comment: @Robbie I think this query will be working fine or you

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee, count(*)-1 as cnt
from t1
group by employee,customer
having cnt > 0;
```

Comment: Although this might be a good answer, please consider adding some more explanation about why this is the right solution and what exactly you are doing :)

Comment: Grouping by employee and customer as repeated occurrence of same pair of employee and customer would count as repeated customer for an employee. Also since we are counting the repeated visits so the first one won't count hence count(*)-1

Answer (score 0):

> IF you COUNT repeat  employee :

```
SELECT id,customer,employee,COUNT(*) FROM USER  GROUP BY employee HAVING COUNT(*)>0
```

[image]

> IF you COUNT repeat customer :

```
SELECT id,customer,employee,COUNT(*) FROM USER  GROUP BY customer HAVING COUNT(*)>0
```

[image]

> //Note: I take total count, you change )COUNT(*)>0 to COUNT(*)>1 
>    && Table=user as

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

/*Data for the table `user` */

```
insert  into `user`(`id`,`customer`,`employee`) 
values (1,'A','Adam'),(2,'A','Adam'),(3,'A','Adam'),(4,'B','Bob'),(5,'C','Adam'),(6,'C','Adam'),(7,'B','Bob'),(8,'D','Dan');
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT customer, employee
  FROM table
GROUP BY customer, employee
  HAVING count(*) > 1